# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sign')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web3js, ethers.js

I'm trying to sign my transaction as previously I was having an error saying `sendTransaction needs signer`. Both `message (encrypted using keccak256)` and `signer` have value but I have no idea why there's an error in the `web3.eth.sign` line.

```js
async function signMessage(message: any, signer: any) {
    console.log(`Message: ${message} annnnd signer: ${signer}` )
    const sig = await web3.eth.sign(message.toString(), signer).then(console.log);
    let v = parseInt(sig.substring(130, 132), 16);
    if (v < 27) v += 27;
    const normalizedSig = `${sig.substring(0, 130)}${v.toString(16)}`;
    return normalizedSig;
};
```

These are my message and signer value:

```
Message: 0x462b880c3d888d1...137ba2fdd16a45817a8a5d 
signer: 0x624b8A9dC...7db4b5dDCd0F7f
```

Comment: error indicates that you did not construct web3 correctly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your browser doesn't have a injected metamask.
So web3.eth is undefined.
Or just try window.web3.eth to get the sign function properly.